# Switch ON/OFF Relay from MQTT flespi using mongoose (javascript) + ESP32

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mqtt, relay

I have project which turns ON and OFF a relay board which is connected to ESP32 (programming using Mongoose OS Javascript). Now, using flespi MQTT, I want to switch ON and OFF the relay by subscribing topic. I have done setup and config the flespi MQTT broker which can turn ON and OFF the relay board by typing any message on the flespi MQTT.

Since, I am new to the MQTT, how do I make only specific message that able to turn ON and OFF the relay when I received(subscribe) from flespi MQTT. For example,
the 'ON Relay' = will turn on relay, 'OFF Relay' = will turn off relay. Only this message will trigger the board.

This is my code:

```
load('api_config.js');
load('api_gpio.js');
load('api_mqtt.js');
load('api_net.js');
load('api_sys.js');
load('api_timer.js');
load('api_adc.js');

let currentState = 0,
  relaypin = 4;

GPIO.set_mode(relaypin, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);

MQTT.sub('topic/#', function(conn, topic, msg) {
  print('Topic', topic, 'message', msg);
  print('ok');
  currentState = 1 - currentState;
  GPIO.write(relaypin, currentState);
  print('Relay is = ' + (currentState ? 'OFF' : 'ON'));

}, null);
```

Comment: Have you tried and `if` statement?

Comment: @hardillb , that will work but now I want to intepret the message that I got from mqtt. I think using the JSON.parse() function, im still looking for it but dont know how to implement it. For example :

In MQTT BROKER, Im sending(publish) "ON" , then my esp32 will subcribe the mqqt and when it detect "ON" command receive then it will run relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im already solved the problem :

```
/*This command will trigger relay 
ON
{
"actuator" : "relay1",
"state": 1
}
OFF
{
"actuator" : "relay1",
"state": 0
}
*/

load('api_config.js');
load('api_gpio.js');
load('api_mqtt.js');
load('api_net.js');
load('api_sys.js');
load('api_timer.js');
load('api_adc.js');

let relaypin = 4;

GPIO.set_mode(relaypin, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);
GPIO.write(relaypin, 1);

MQTT.sub('my/rainsensor', function(conn, topic, payload)
{
    let test = JSON.parse(payload);
    print('Topic:', topic, 'actuator type:', test.actuator, 'state:', test.state);

    //Check if '1' received and trigger relay ON
    if (1 === test.state) 
    {
    GPIO.write(relaypin, 0);
    print('Relay is = ON');
    }

    else if (0 === test.state) 
    {
    GPIO.write(relaypin, 1);
    print('Relay is = OFF');
    }

    else
    {
      print('WRONG COMMAND!!!');
    }
}, null);
```